# Custom Design Pattern, e.g. IDisposable Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, visual-studio-2015

Short version: How can I create my own pattern binded to a interface, just like IDisposable Pattern Snippet?

Long version: Whenever I implement a "IDisposable", Visual Studio 2015 offers me an option to implement IDisposable Pattern and it writes some code to my class... So, how can I have my own pattern to implement with a certain interface (create by me)?

The idea is that all the developers can have an clue of how to implement a certain interface with the correct "pattern".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a snippet from within Visual Studio.

MSDN have a nice [walk through](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx)